# Send Push Notifications to Devices and web Browsers using Laravel FCM

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using following package to send notifications to broswers.

> https://github.com/kawankoding/laravel-fcm

The code to send Notifications,

```
fcm()
    ->to($recipients) // $recipients must an array
    ->notification([
        'title' => 'Test FCM',
        'body' => 'This is a test of FCM',
    ])
    ->send();
```

This is working fine for browser.

**Question**: can the $recipients array contain both types i,e, device tokens (Android & iOS) and browsers(FF & Chrome) Tokens ?

Answer (score 0):

No.
You can send Notification/Data only to iOS/Android devices.

Comment: But I could send the message with this code to browsers. I am not sure about devices